# activity mainactivity is not responding

Tags: android

The major problem am getting is "main activity not responding".when i run in the emulator it says the main activity is not responding,force to close.I am stuck up with this project for past three days and the project is about twitter.In "main activity" am passing twitter consumer key and secret.[The source code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) could any one explain me whats the problem in the code.this is my first project.

```
     package com.androidhive.twitterconnect

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Constants
/**
 * Register your here apps https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
 * consumer key and secret
 * */
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "consumer key";
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = " consumer secret";

// Preference Constants
static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

// Twitter oauth urls
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

// Login button
Button btnLoginTwitter;
// Update status button
Button btnUpdateStatus;
// Logout button
Button btnLogoutTwitter;
// EditText for update
EditText txtUpdate;
// lbl update
TextView lblUpdate;
TextView lblUserName;

// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Twitter
private static Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken requestToken;

// Shared Preferences
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

// Internet Connection detector
private ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet connection error", "please connect to working internet connection", false);


      // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if twitter keys are set
    if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog
        (MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // All UI elements

    btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
    btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
    btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
    txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
    lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
    lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", 0);

    /**
     * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
     * */
    btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call login twitter function
            loginToTwitter();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
     * function
     * */
    btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call update status function
            // Get the status from EditText
            String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

            // Check for blank text
            if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                // update status
                new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
            } else {
                // EditText is empty
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event for logout from twitter
     * */
    btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call logout twitter function
            logoutFromTwitter();
        }
    });

    /** This if conditions is tested once is
     * redirected from twitter page. Parse the uri to get oAuth
     * Verifier
     * */
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            // oAuth verifier
            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                // Get the access token
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        requestToken, verifier);

                // Shared Preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                // After getting access token, access token secret
                // store them in application preferences
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                        accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes

                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                // Hide login button
                btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Show Update Twitter
                lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Getting user details from twitter
                // For now i am getting his name only
                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();

                // Displaying in xml ui
                lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Check log for login errors
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
            }
    }

}

/**
 * Function to login twitter
 * */
private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // user already logged into twitter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Function to update status
 * */
class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String args[]) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
     * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
     * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Clearing EditText field
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}

/**
 * Function to logout from twitter
 * It will just clear the application shared preferences
 * */
private void logoutFromTwitter() {
    // Clear the shared preferences
    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
    e.commit();

    // After this take the appropriate action
    // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
    // You might not needed this code
    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUserName.setText("");
    lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
 * fetched from Shared Preferences
 * */
private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
    // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
    return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Comment: did u changed the manifest ?

Comment: You're probably doing some long network operation on UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Add your activity to your manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ur activity in manifest as follows:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Also try registering your components of mainActivity btn.SetOnClicklistener():